# localhost refused to connect in Webapi operation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, localhost, windows-10, firewall

I have created WebApi project and include sample Get method.
When I am trying to access the get method using url (http://localhost:port/api/video) from Firefox/Chrome browser I am getting below message:-

This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I created ASP.NET web application and try to view aspx page using localhost in browser then it is showing the page.

When I am trying to run WebAPI withing Visual Studio then it open the url(http://localhost:port) in Google Chrome with HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden error.

I am using IIS Express with Visual Studio 2015 Community. OS is Windows 10.

I have tried to turned off firewall and remove # from hosts.config file but it never worked.

Is there anything that I can do because I am directionless now after looking out for same issue for last 2-3 days?

Please find my code below:-

**Global.asax.cs**

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
```

**VideoController.cs**

```
public class VideoController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[]{ "Value1", "Value2"};
        }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
           // config.EnableCors();
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show your Web API controller with sample Get method?

Comment: For starters you should be testing API endpoints with Fiddler or PostMan etc. not a browser, however a GET that is not expecting any parameters will dump the JSON onto the screen in Chrome. You will need to share some of your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I have added the code as requested. I have used fiddler and it was giving following exception on Get method:- "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I am able to run WebAPI in localhost.

I have checked all options in Control Panel->Turn Windows feature on or off->Internet Information Services->World Wide Web Services-> Application Development Features|Common HTTP Features|Security.

Checking all this option allow me to get response from GET Requests when I debug Web API application from Visual Studio 2015. But as soon as I stop debugging application in Visual Studio, the response from GET Requests also stooped. I find that IIS express also stopped when I stop debugging in Visual Studio. 
After reading several posts I come to know that I have to uncheck option "Enable Edit and Continue" from Web API Project->Properties->Web->Enable Edit and Continue.

But I have to use GET response even when I don't start Visual Studio at all so I finally deploy my site in IIS.

Answer (score 3):

You could also close Visual studios, Delete the .vs folder (may be hidden) then recompile the application. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue "localhost refused to connect" poped up after rebooted PC.

What solved my issue is that I hit the button **"Create Virtual Directory"** in Project property page.

`Web API Project->Properties->Web->"Create Virtual Directory"`